# Overlap of rectangle

Tags: html, css

Below is the image I am trying for; I managed to get a rectangle using CSS, but I am trying for a rectangle above another one .

[image]

```css
#dragtarget2 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 176px;
  height: 76px;
  background: #968282;
  border-radius: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget2">
  <p>meter</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you. Please complete it to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Make your rectangles `position: absolute` and the container as `position: relative`. 
This is the code you're looking for.

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
}

.first , .second, .third {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.second{
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
}

.third{
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PradeepRamisetti Glad it did, Can you accept the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute`/`position: relative` to move element from it's origin position. Use `z-index` to move element above/below other elements (higher `z-index` - higher element is positioned).

```css
.border {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
.border:nth-child(2) {
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 6;
}
.border:nth-child(3) {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 7;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
  /* NOTE: this does not effect absolute elements */
  padding: 10px;
  /* NOTE: this will be origin of absolute elements coordinates */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="border">1</div>
  <div class="border">2</div>
  <div class="border origin">SmartMeter</div>
</div>
```

---

With less HTML:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}
.border {
  position: relative;
}
.border span,
.border:before,
.border:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.border:after {
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 6;
}
.border span {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="border"><span>SmartMeter</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added two outer divs so that the code is as follows.

```css
#dragtarget2 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 176px;
  height: 76px;
  background: #968282;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 2px;
}
.dragtarget0 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 176px;
  height: 76px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.dragtarget1 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 176px;
  height: 76px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 13px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dragtarget0">
  <div class="dragtarget1">
    <div id="dragtarget2">
      <p>meter</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```